# Can I call a stored MySQL function from PHP if SELECT is not allowed?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I've created a stored function in MySQL, and it works fine with the query:

> SELECT my_function(param);

Now I'd like to call it from PHP. But SELECT is forbidden to PHP "user" of my database. Should I rewrite the function as a procedure, or is there a way to call it without "SELECT"?

Comment: look like the mysql's user used by your PHP is not granted to execute a stored function. try execute `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION my_db.my_function TO 'user_php'@'localhost' identified by 'userpassword';`

Comment: EXECUTE rights are granted, I've set them myself. CALLing procedures works fine. I don't want to allow SELECT though, hence the question.

Comment: oh i see, do you have another database that SELECT is granted? if you do then you can call your function with `select my_function('param') FROM my_other_db.my_table LIMIT 1;`